# Need help copying the input from a function as the input for another function in R

Tags: r, data.table

I need help determining how I can use the input for the function below as an input for another r file.

```
Hotel <- function(hotel) {

  require(data.table)

  dat <- read.csv("demo.csv", header = TRUE)

  dat$Date <- as.Date(paste0(format(strptime(as.character(dat$Date), 
                                             "%m/%d/%y"), 
                                    "%Y/%m"),"/1"))

  library(data.table)
  table <- setDT(dat)[, list(Revenue = sum(Revenues),
                             Hours = sum(Hours),
                             Index = mean(Index)), 
                      by = list(Hotel, Date)]


  answer <- na.omit(table[table$Hotel == hotel, ])

  if (nrow(answer) == 0) {
    stop("invalid hotel")
  }

  return(answer)
}
```

I would input **Hotel("Hotel Name")**

Here's the other R file using the Hotel name I inputted above.

```
#Reads the dataframe from the Hotel Function
star <- (Hotel("Hotel Name")) 

#Calculates the Revpolu and Index
Revpolu <- star$Revenue / star$Hours
Index <- star$Index

png(filename = "~/Desktop/result.png", width = 480, height= 480)
plot(Index, Revpolu, main = "Hotel Name", col = "green", pch = 20)

testing <- cor.test(Index, Revpolu)

write.table(testing[["p.value"]], file = "output.csv", sep = ";", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

I would like for this part to become automated instead of having to copy and paste from the first file an input and then storing it as a variable. Or if it's easier, then make all of this just one function.

Also instead of having to input one Hotel name for the function. Is it possible to make the first file read all the hotel names if they are identified as row names in the .csv file and have that input read in the second file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example is not reproducible and your code has some bugs (using the column "Rooms" which is not produced by your function), I can't give you a tested answer, but here's how you can structure your code to produce the statistics you want for all hotels without having to copy and paste hotel names:

```
library(data.table)

# Use fread instead of read.csv, it's faster
dat <- fread("demo.csv", header = TRUE)

dat[, Date := as.Date(paste0(format(strptime(as.character(Date), "%m/%d/%y"), "%Y/%m"),"/1"))

table <- dat[, list(
  Revenue = sum(Revenues),
  Hours = sum(Hours),
  Index = mean(Index)
  ), by = list(Hotel, Date)]

# You might want to consider using na.rm=TRUE in cor.test instead of 
# using na.omit, but I kept it here to keep the result similar.
answer <- na.omit(table)

# Calculate Revpolu inside the data.table
table[, Revpolu := Revenue / Hours]

# You can compute a p-value for all hotels using a group by
testing <- table[, list(p.value = cor.test(Index, Revpolu)[["p.value"]]), by=Hotel]
write.table(testing, file = "output.csv", sep = ";", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

# You can get individual plots for each hotel with a for loop
hotels <- unique(table$Hotel)
for (h in hotels) {
  png(filename = "~/Desktop/result.png", width = 480, height= 480)
  plot(table[Hotel == h, Index], table[Hotel == h, Revpolu], main = h, col = "green", pch = 20)
  dev.off()  
}
```

Comment: @Y T I fixed my original code. Please apply your code above. I tried but it gave me errors. I think you may have missed the fact that at the same time I inputted a hotel name I stored it as a variable called "star"

Comment: I edited my code to reflect your changes. Again, since your example is not reproducible (it relies on demo.csv which is not available to me), I can't test my code, so rather than running my code as is, use it as a suggestion on how to structure your code to get the desired result.

Comment: How do I eliminate the "Nan" I get from the Hours column within my Table List? Apparently when dividing Revenues and Hours I have in some cases zero hours which creates unnecessary Nan values...

Comment: You can do something like `table <- table[!is.na(Revpolu)]` to keep only rows that have a valid Revpolu result.